# Mapping through an array of objects with one nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have an array of objects, each object contains two elements and an array of links that should appear in an element.

```
const array = [
    {
      text: "x",
      icon: "x",
      links: [
        { link: "www.google.com", title: "ABC" },
        { link: "www.linkedin.com", title: "CDE" },
      ],
    },
    {
      text: "y",
      icon: "y",
      links: [
        { link: "www.twitter.com", title: "Google" },
        { link: "www.facebook.com", title: "Linkedin" },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

This is my return

```
{array.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <div>
                <div>{item.icon}</div>
                <div>{item.text}</div>
              </div>
              <div>
                {item.links.map((links, i) => (
                  <a className={STYLES.link} key={i} href={link.link}>
                    <div>{link.title}</div>
                  </a>;
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        ))}
```

Need to be able to pull the first link object out of the link array (i.e. `{ link: "www.twitter.com", title: "Google" },`) I want it to appear in the list at the top and wrapped in a different div to dictate sticky styling.

Comment: What is testNav in your example?

Comment: i think it should be `item.links` instead of `testnav` isn't it ?

Comment: Look at your second map, you need to return if you use a new block. Use the ( for replacing {

Comment: Also you single link object is link not links.link. Should change with link.link here. And I dont like the naming. So if you look at my answer that's why I call mine itemLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace testNav by the unique item you already get from the map as first argument. Also in your second map you do `=> {` if you do this you need to have return keyword there. If you replace `{` with `(` you dont need.

```
{nav.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <div>
                <div>{item.icon}</div>
                <div>{item.text}</div>
              </div>
              <div>
                {item.links.map((itemLink, i) => (
                  <a className={STYLES.link} key={itemLink.link} href={itemLink.link}>
                    <div>{itemLink.title}</div>
                  </a>;
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: This will not work. item is an Object not an array. you need `item.links`

Comment: Ya sorry I just update, thank you to let me know @CodeManiac

Comment: this worked! swapping the `{` for an `(` and changing the second map. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user10782250 happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `testNav` is in your proposed solution.
Try and replace `testNav` with `item.links`. I haven't tested this code but I imagine it will look like this:

```
{nav.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <div>
            <div>{item.icon}</div>
            <div>{item.text}</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            {item.links.map((link, i) => {
              return (    
                  <a className={STYLES.link} key={i} href={link.link}>
                    <div>{link.title}</div>
                  </a>;
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

You may want to consider renaming your properties as `link.link` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: You need to return if you use { with arrow, you should replace it with (

Comment: You're right @EQuimper, thank you. I prefer to be a little bit more verbose and use return though. I updated the snippet.